# Why is swapping characters this way valid JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, character, swap

I am getting confused on how this snippet of code works.  I would assume that the `A` would need to be `'A'` in order for these two characters to swap, but it works.  Also, is there a name for what this is doing? From the looks of it, I think it is destructuring, but I'm not certain.

```
var translations = {
  A : 'U'
};
console.log(translations['A']); //returns U
```

I would have assumed you need to write it this way:

```
var translations = {
  'A' : 'U'
};
console.log(translations['A']); //also returns U
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ud37asp8/14/

Comment: Object or property keys can be either an identifier name (i.e. identifiers + reserved words), a string literal, or a numeric literal. It does not really matter whether you call it `A` or `'A'` in the way of accessing it. https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object or property keys can be either an identifier name (i.e. identifiers + reserved words), a string literal, or a numeric literal. It does not really matter whether you call it `A` or `'A'` in the way of accessing it. https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer

### Property names

> Property names must be strings. This means that non-string objects
>   cannot be used as keys in the object. Any non-string object, including
>   a number, is typecasted into a string via the toString method.

```
var object = {};
object['1'] = 'value';
console.log(object[1]);
```

> This outputs "value", since 1 is type-casted into '1'.

```
var foo = {unique_prop: 1}, bar = {unique_prop: 2}, object = {};
object[foo] = 'value';
console.log(object[bar]);
```

> This also outputs "value", since both foo and bar are converted to the
>   same string. In the SpiderMonkey JavaScript engine, this string would
>   be "['object Object']".

Also what you are doing is basically creating an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). I do not see you destroying it anywhere.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

### Creating objects

> However, the advantage of the literal or initializer notation is, that
>   you are able to quickly create objects with properties inside the
>   curly braces. You simply notate a list of key: value pairs delimited
>   by comma. The following code creates an object with three properties
>   and the keys are "foo", "age" and "baz". The values of these keys are
>   a string "bar", a number 42, and another object.

```
var object = {
  foo: 'bar',
  age: 42,
  baz: {myProp: 12}
}
```

### Accessing properties

> Once you have created an object, you might want to read or change
>   them. Object properties can be accessed by using the dot notation or
>   the bracket notation. See [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for detailed information.

```
object.foo; // "bar"
object['age']; // 42

object.foo = 'baz';
```

> One can think of an object as an associative array (a.k.a. map,
>   dictionary, hash, lookup table). The keys in this array are the names
>   of the object's properties. It's typical when speaking of an object's
>   properties to make a distinction between properties and methods.
>   However, the property/method distinction is little more than a
>   convention. A method is simply a property that can be called, for
>   example if it has a reference to a Function instance as its value.

Comment: Thank you, this helped explain so much! I am still having a tough time understanding the second example with unique_prop. Is there a resource I could use to understand it better?

Comment: @Ryan Wendell: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors